# Artisan says class name not defined, even though it is?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I have created the following Artisan command in Laravel:

```
class draft_cron extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'draft_cron';
    //etc
```

And in `start/artisan.php` I added:

```
Artisan::add(new draft_cron);
```

However, when I try to run the command, I get an error saying `Class 'draft_cron' not found` and pointing to the above line from `start/artisan.php`.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things: 1 is what user RDelorier said. DraftCron instead of draft_cron. The other thing is, did you do composer dump-autoload?

Comment: After changing draft_cron to DraftCron I still get the same error. However, after doing dump-autoload, I'm getting the error `command DraftCron is not defined`.

Comment: Did you change Artisan::add(new draft_cron); for Artisan::add(new DraftCron);?

Comment: Yes I did, before dumping the autoload.

Comment: mm just to review, you edited the filename, the class name in the command, modified the artisan add method with the new name and dump-autoload?

Comment: Works now when I call it through the console - the issue was with the "example" arguments that were added to the class automatically, and I was calling the command with no arguments. However, still throws the same error when I call it through cron like `php /path-to-laravel-here/artisan DraftCron`. Any ideas?

Comment: mm what happens if you type the complete path to your php installation too? instead of only php ...

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely culprit is PSR cant figure out where the class is, any particular reason you used snake_case over StudlyCase?